# SQLite3 connecting to C program and using inner loops to iterate through results - what do?

Tags: c, ubuntu, sqlite

:D
  I am reading definitive guide to sqlite (owens, allen) and decided to actually experiment with some of the code in this fine book and ran into some compilation problems. I was hoping to crowd source some of these problems and learn some C and SQLite at the same time! whoa yeah!

I receive the following mysterious compilation errors upon compiling this:
gcc mo.c -o m -lsqlite3

```
mo.c: In function ‘main’:
mo.c:22:44: error: ‘nrows’ undeclared (first use in this function)
mo.c:22:44: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function
it appears in
mo.c:22:52: error: ‘ncols’ undeclared (first use in this function)
mo.c:22:2: warning: passing argument 3 of ‘sqlite3_get_table’ from incompatible pointer 
type [enabled by default]
/usr/local/include/sqlite3.h:2084:16: note: expected ‘char ***’ but argument is of  
type  ‘char * (*)[50]’
```

I am most confused by "warning: passing argument 3 of 'sqlite3_get_table' from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]" and "note: expected 'char ***' but argument is of type 'char * (*)[50]'

the program in question is below: can you make it go stackoverflow?
<===================================================================================>

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sqlite3.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
sqlite3 *db;
char *zErr;
int rc;
char *sql;
char *result[50];
int j=0;
int i=0;
rc = sqlite3_open("foods-backup.db", &db);

if(rc) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Can't open database: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
    sqlite3_close(db);
    exit(1);
}

rc = sqlite3_get_table(db, sql, &result, &nrows, &ncols, &zErr);

for(i; i < nrows; i++) {
  for(j; j < ncols; j++) {
    /* the i+1 term skips over the first record,
    which is the column headers */
    fprintf(stdout, "%s", result[(i+1)*ncols + j]);
  }
}



if(rc != SQLITE_OK) {
    if (zErr != NULL) {
  fprintf(stderr, "SQL error: %s\n", zErr);
        sqlite3_free(zErr);
    }
}



 /* Free memory */
sqlite3_free_table(result);
// close database connection or something and return everything is okay i guess
sqlite3_close(db);
return 0;
} // end main
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The errors which you are getting are because of
1. `nrows`, `ncols` variables are not declared. They should be declared as integers.
2. `result` variable should be declared as `char **` rather than `char *result[50]`.

So comment out your result array pointer declaration and copy below two lines. Hope this helps.

```
int nrows, ncols;
char **result;
```

http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/free_table.html

```
int sqlite3_get_table(
sqlite3 *db,          /* An open database */
const char *zSql,     /* SQL to be evaluated */
char ***pazResult,    /* Results of the query */
int *pnRow,           /* Number of result rows written here */
int *pnColumn,        /* Number of result columns written here */
char **pzErrmsg       /* Error msg written here */
```

);

Comment: Do you know how to format the output? I can not add `sql= ".mode column;.header ON; select * from foods;"` to my query...

Comment: I don't think there will be any options which will provide output with header information. I have worked with other DB API, always the result returned back contains the table column values which you have requested in the sql statement (i.e if it is a select stmt and processed successfully)

Comment: Hmm, seems like I am out of luck on formatting in a C program. If I add `j=0' in the outer loop and re-initialize this inner loop variable I get the whole table in my shell unformatted and its tough to read. Thank-you for your help @prashantsunkari